# How to divide a picture into many <div>?

Tags: html

I do this by using that pictrure as the background of a big div, then I make many small div inside covering the whole area of the big div, but I think it seems very unprofessional. Is there anyway to divide a picture into may div ??

Comment: I'm just trying to creat a lot of div without typing over and over again div. is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Try [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position).

Answer (score 0):

If your image is: `big_picture.png`, and it is 100px x 100px, then a super-simplistic example of the solution is:

```
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

css:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(big_picture.png);
}

/* will only reveal the top 50 pixels */
div.top {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

/* will only reveal the lower 50 pixels */
div.bottom {
    background-position: 0px -50px;
}
```

You can clearly apply this to as many div elements as you like, in a grid.

Comment: is there any way to create a lot of div without tying div a lot of time ?

Comment: @user3341783 Sure.  There Are javascript libraries that will do that for you: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/11/23/how-to-slice-images-into-tiles-with-jquery-and-css3-transitions/